# Problems with postfix/dovecot unable to receive mail

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, dovecot

Can't receive mail on my server but can send just fine.

From what I can tell in the logs, it complains about timing out. I check the connection externally using telnet from my PC, I can connect to port 25 fine.

It also talks about failing to do something with mysql, so I extended the time-out limits slightly and checked to make sure I could connect using myphpadmin. everything seems peachy from that aspect, so I don't know why it's complaining there.

With the help of @roaima it now bounces messages, but it claims that "loops back to myself".
If you look at the my.cnf of postfix, you can see that I've tried many different orientations of mydestination, some say it loops back, other say it's not a relay host.
After researching the error I'm having, it claims that either removing or adding my FQDN fixes it, however in both cases I've met with no success.

I'm alright at using Linux but postfix escapes me.

Log of: /var/log/mail.log

```
Apr 22 15:26:37 webserver postfix/smtpd[36202]: connect from mail-wi0-f172.google.com[209.85.212.172]
Apr 22 15:26:38 webserver postfix/trivial-rewrite[36209]: warning: do not list domain zomgaming.net in BOTH mydestination and virtual_mailbox_domains
Apr 22 15:26:38 webserver postfix/smtpd[36202]: 20547C0E08: client=mail-wi0-f172.google.com[209.85.212.172]
Apr 22 15:26:38 webserver postfix/cleanup[36212]: 20547C0E08: message-id=<CAF++Fz1DrsMktsZ4k=FMRtjwfHP3mfPbVL2QoXxemqX_M69wkQ@mail.gmail.com>
Apr 22 15:26:38 webserver postfix/qmgr[36200]: 20547C0E08: from=<deathmock@gmail.com>, size=1677, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 22 15:26:38 webserver amavis[50731]: (50731-11) NOTICE: reconnecting in response to: err=2006, HY000, DBD::mysql::st execute failed: MySQL server has gone away at (eval 136) line 170, <GEN31> line 770.
Apr 22 15:26:38 webserver postfix/smtpd[36202]: disconnect from mail-wi0-f172.google.com[209.85.212.172]
Apr 22 15:26:41 webserver postfix/smtpd[36216]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Apr 22 15:26:41 webserver postfix/smtpd[36216]: 7FBF9C0E3B: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Apr 22 15:26:41 webserver postfix/cleanup[36212]: 7FBF9C0E3B: message-id=<CAF++Fz1DrsMktsZ4k=FMRtjwfHP3mfPbVL2QoXxemqX_M69wkQ@mail.gmail.com>
Apr 22 15:26:41 webserver postfix/qmgr[36200]: 7FBF9C0E3B: from=<deathmock@gmail.com>, size=2151, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 22 15:26:41 webserver postfix/smtpd[36216]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Apr 22 15:26:41 webserver amavis[50731]: (50731-11) Passed CLEAN {RelayedOpenRelay}, [209.85.212.172]:36328 [209.85.212.172] <deathmock@gmail.com> -> <admin@zomgaming.net>, Queue-ID: 20547C0E08, Message-ID: <CAF++Fz1DrsMktsZ4k=FMRtjwfH$
Apr 22 15:26:41 webserver postfix/smtp[36213]: 20547C0E08: to=<admin@zomgaming.net>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=3.5, delays=0.25/0.01/0.01/3.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 from MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025): 250 2.0.0 $
Apr 22 15:26:41 webserver postfix/qmgr[36200]: 20547C0E08: removed
Apr 22 15:26:41 webserver postfix/smtp[36217]: 7FBF9C0E3B: to=<admin@zomgaming.net>, relay=none, delay=0.28, delays=0.02/0.04/0.23/0, dsn=5.4.6, status=bounced (mail for mail.zomgaming.net loops back to myself)
Apr 22 15:26:41 webserver postfix/cleanup[36212]: C7091C16D3: message-id=<20150422152641.C7091C16D3@webserver.zomgaming.com>
Apr 22 15:26:41 webserver postfix/qmgr[36200]: C7091C16D3: from=<>, size=4101, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 22 15:26:41 webserver postfix/bounce[36218]: 7FBF9C0E3B: sender non-delivery notification: C7091C16D3
Apr 22 15:26:41 webserver postfix/qmgr[36200]: 7FBF9C0E3B: removed
Apr 22 15:26:42 webserver postfix/smtp[36217]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400d:c06::1b]:25: Network is unreachable
Apr 22 15:26:43 webserver postfix/smtp[36217]: C7091C16D3: to=<deathmock@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.22.27]:25, delay=1.5, delays=0.01/0.01/0.62/0.85, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1429716403 gn1si5368338$
Apr 22 15:26:43 webserver postfix/qmgr[36200]: C7091C16D3: removed
Apr 22 15:29:58 webserver postfix/anvil[36205]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:209.85.212.172) at Apr 22 15:26:37
Apr 22 15:29:58 webserver postfix/anvil[36205]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:209.85.212.172) at Apr 22 15:26:37
Apr 22 15:29:58 webserver postfix/anvil[36205]: statistics: max message rate 1/60s for (smtp:209.85.212.172) at Apr 22 15:26:38
Apr 22 15:29:58 webserver postfix/anvil[36205]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Apr 22 15:26:37
Apr 22 15:30:02 webserver postfix/smtpd[36282]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Apr 22 15:30:02 webserver dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (disconnected before auth was ready, waited 0 secs): user=<>, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured, session=<zbw01lEUXgB/AAAB>
Apr 22 15:30:02 webserver dovecot: pop3-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, secured, session=<kQk11lEUFAB/AAAB>
Apr 22 15:30:02 webserver postfix/smtpd[36282]: lost connection after CONNECT from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Apr 22 15:30:02 webserver postfix/smtpd[36282]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
```

Output of: dig mx zomgaming.net

```
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.2-Ubuntu <<>> mx zomgaming.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 44151
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;zomgaming.net.                 IN      MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
zomgaming.net.          3599    IN      MX      1 zomgaming.net.

;; Query time: 66 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Apr 13 10:34:04 UTC 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 58
```

My mx records on godaddy:

```
MX 1 zomgamgin.net.
MX 5 mail.zomgaming.net.
```

Output of: /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
#192.168.1.204  webserver.zomgaming.com webserver
192.168.1.204   zomgaming.net
#192.168.1.204  mail.zomgaming.net
73.172.71.230   webserver.zomgaming.com webserver
#73.172.71.230  zomgaming.net
127.0.0.1       mail.zomgaming.net
```

Output of /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = webserver.zomgaming.com
mydomain = zomgaming.net
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
#mydestination = webserver.zomgaming.com, localhost, localhost.localdomain
#mydestination = $myhostname localhost.$mydomain localhost $mydomain mail.$mydomain
#mydestination = webserver.zomgaming.com localhost.webserver.zomgaming.com localhost zomgaming.net mail.zomgaming.net
#mydestination = $mydomain, localhost.localdomain, localhost
#mydestination = $myhostname, localhost, localhost.localdomain
mydestination = webserver.zomgaming.com zomgaming.net
#relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128 192.168.1.0/24
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
#virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/virtual-mailman, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_recipient.cf
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
transport_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/transport-mailman, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_transports.cf
relay_domains =
relay_recipient_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relayrecipientmaps.cf
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_can$
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender.cf
smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_client.cf
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 100
maildrop_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
maildrop_destination_recipient_limit = 1
virtual_transport = dovecot
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks
nested_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/nested_header_checks
body_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/body_checks
owner_request_special = no
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
message_size_limit = 0
smtp_host_lookup = native
```

Output of /etc/postfix/master.cf:

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d vmail ${extension} ${recipient} ${user} ${nexthop} ${sender}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
scalemail-backend unix  -       n       n       -       2       pipe
flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}

dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DROhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f ${sender} -d ${user}@${nexthop}
amavis unix - - - - 2 smtp
        -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
        -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes

127.0.0.1:10025 inet n - - - - smtpd
        -o content_filter=
        -o local_recipient_maps=
        -o relay_recipient_maps=
        -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
        -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
        -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
        -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
        -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
        -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
        -o strict_rfc821_envelopes=yes
        -o receive_override_options=no_unknown_recipient_checks,no_header_body_checks
```

Output of "hostname":

```
webserver.zomgaming.com
```

Output of "hostname -f":

```
webserver.zomgaming.com
```

Connection from an outside source:

```
220 webserver.zomgaming.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
>ehlo zomgaming.net
250-webserver.zomgaming.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
>mail from:<deathmock@gmail.com>
501 5.5.4 Syntax: MAIL FROM:<address>
>mail from:<steve@example.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok
>rcpt to:<admin@zomgaming.net>
502 5.5.2 Error: command not recognized
>mail to:<admin@zomgaming.net>
503 5.5.1 Error: nested MAIL command
>rcpt to:<admin@zomgaming.net>
250 2.1.5 Ok
>data
354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
>this is a test
>.
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 648FFC128A
>quit
```

log:

```
Apr 13 09:17:28 webserver postfix/qmgr[31156]: 648FFC128A: from=<steve@example.com>, size=329, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 13 09:17:43 webserver postfix/smtpd[34632]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Apr 13 09:17:43 webserver postfix/smtpd[34632]: 950C9C39CC: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Apr 13 09:17:43 webserver postfix/cleanup[34617]: 950C9C39CC: message-id=<20150413091743.950C9C39CC@webserver.zomgaming.com>
Apr 13 09:17:43 webserver postfix/qmgr[31156]: 950C9C39CC: from=<steve@example.com>, size=1013, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 13 09:17:43 webserver postfix/smtpd[34632]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Apr 13 09:17:43 webserver amavis[1254]: (01254-18) Passed BAD-HEADER-7 {RelayedOpenRelay,Quarantined}, [24.210.201.75]:12825 [24.210.201.75] <steve@exam$
Apr 13 09:17:43 webserver postfix/smtp[34629]: 648FFC128A: to=<admin@zomgaming.net>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, delay=165, delays=150/0.01/0.01/1$
Apr 13 09:17:43 webserver postfix/qmgr[31156]: 648FFC128A: removed
Apr 13 09:17:57 webserver postfix/smtpd[34531]: disconnect from cpe-24-210-201-75.neo.res.rr.com[24.210.201.75]
Apr 13 09:18:54 webserver postfix/smtp[34633]: connect to zomgaming.net[73.172.71.230]:25: Connection timed out
Apr 13 09:18:54 webserver postfix/smtp[34633]: 950C9C39CC: to=<admin@zomgaming.net>, relay=none, delay=70, delays=0.02/0.04/70/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to zomgaming.net[73.172.71.230]:25: Connection timed out)
```

Ok so I'll try to connect to myself internally.

```
root@webserver:/home/admin# telnet zomgaming.net 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to mail.zomgaming.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 webserver.zomgaming.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
```

Output of /etc/nsswitch.conf:

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Comment: Sending a message is more than connecting to port 25. Did you "send" an email by telnetting into port 25 **from outside** and go through the send an email exchange? If not do so and make sure the machine receives a message from outside. Once it does and check the logs where it goes internally.

Comment: @Anthon Updated post with request.

Comment: Can you do `telnet localhost 25`, this looks like some firewall restriction on  73.172.71.230 if you can.

Comment: -1 your question is full of errors you didn't even bother to proofread for such as showing us`dig` output confirming that `zomgamgin.net` does not exist when that is not even the domain you are using, syntax errors in your SMTP transcript, etc... Moreover, you should fix each underlying problem that you can see wuch as the MySQL connection problem and the port 25 TCP connection problem, *then afterwards* see about Postfix.

Comment: @anthon Seems to work fine

telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.

Comment: @Celada Woops, didn't even notice that. fixed.

Answer (score 0):

We can see that your web server is also your mail server, and that `webserver.zomgaming.com` is the same host as `zomgaming.net`.

Postfix knows that it is running on `webserver.zomgaming.com`, as evidenced by the 220 banner for inbound SMTP connections. However, it seems that Postfix does not know that it is also `zomgaming.net` (as per your `/etc/hosts` file), so when it receives an email for `admin@zomgaming.net` it tries to connect to that "remote" host for onward delivery. Most sane mailers refuse to talk to themselves, so even if it could talk to itself via 127.0.0.1 the attempt is bound to fail.

Take a look at the `mydestination` configuration option in `main.cf`

```
mydestination = webserver.zomgaming.com zomgaming.net
```

Comment: Alright i added the main.cf file. What should it look like if my hostname for the computer is webserver.zomgaming.com. I was folowing a tutorial when i set it up.

Comment: @Steven you should already have one

Comment: No i mean i added it to the above section.

Comment: @StevenVenham is the problem resolved? If not, please provide an updated set of debugging information (log files are good).

Comment: Iv updated the post, i been trying everything i can think of, so alot has changed.

Comment: @StevenVenham thank you for the updates. It's strange: postfix seems still to think that zomgaming.net has your external IP, but your `/etc/hosts` file clearly indicates it's `127.0.0.1`. The `telnet zomgaming.net 25` should also hit `127.0.0.1` but it isn't (unless you've not yet updated that in your Question). In `/etc/nsswitch.conf` does the `hosts` line have `files dns` or `dns files`? It should have `files` first, so that `/etc/hosts` gets priority over DNS lookups.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22818/discussion-between-steven-venham-and-roaima).